# NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.JoinColumn.foreignKey()

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jpa, openshift

I'm trying to deploy my application on OpenShift (JBoss Enterprise Application Platform 6) and I get the NoSuchMethodError mentioned in the title. So I googled the whole thing and found a few articles or threads that mentioned that this Method is available since JPA-API 2.1. I found out that a dependency that is necessary for Openshift contains the JPA-API 2.0. I tried to exclude this dependency but it does not work. Any ideas? Please find the pom.xml below.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>christmasmarkets</groupId>
<artifactId>christmasmarkets</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0</version>
<name>christmasmarkets</name>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>eap</id>
        <url>http://maven.repository.redhat.com/techpreview/all</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>springsource-repo</id>
        <name>SpringSource Repository</name>
        <url>http://repo.springsource.org/release</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>eap</id>
        <url>http://maven.repository.redhat.com/techpreview/all</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
    <spring.version>4.1.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <hibernate.version>4.3.7.Final</hibernate.version>
    <hibernate-annotations.version>3.5.6-Final</hibernate-annotations.version>
    <hibernate-commons-annotations.version>3.2.0.Final</hibernate-commons-annotations.version>
    <jackson.version>2.2.3</jackson.version>
    <postgre.version>9.3-1102-jdbc41</postgre.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2.Final-redhat-4</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>${postgre.version}</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <!-- When built in OpenShift the 'openshift' profile will be used when 
            invoking mvn. -->
        <!-- Use this profile for any OpenShift specific customization your app 
            will need. -->
        <!-- By default that is to put the resulting archive into the 'deployments' 
            folder. -->
        <!-- http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-building-for-different-environments.html -->
        <id>openshift</id>
        <build>
            <finalName>christmasmarkets</finalName>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>deployments</outputDirectory>
                        <warName>ROOT</warName>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that JPA 2.0 is provided *at runtime* by the container. Exclusion of the provided dependency in `pom.xml` has effect only at compile time. To solve this problem you must configure class loading in the container.

OpenShift JavaEE 6 support is based on JBoss AS 7. From [Class Loading in AS7](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Class+Loading+in+AS7) documentation:

> jboss-deployment-structure.xml is a JBoss specific deployment
>   descriptor that can be used to control class loading in a fine grained
>   manner. It should be placed in the top level deployment, in META-INF
>   (or WEB-INF for web deployments). It can do the following:
>
> ```
>    Prevent automatic dependencies from being added
>    Add additional dependencies
>    ...
> ```

So what you need is to add a custom `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` file to exclude `hibernate-jpa-2.0-api` from being added automatically.

Based on [OpenShift's documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6/html/Development_Guide/Prevent_a_Module_Being_Implicitly_Loaded.html):

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
   <deployment>
      <exclusions>
         <module name="javax.persistence.api" />
      </exclusions>
   </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Comment: where should I place this xml file ?

Comment: @H.Aqjn "It should be placed in the top level deployment, in META-INF (or WEB-INF for web deployments)"

Answer (score 0):

Add this Maven dependency to your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```